# sinch calling app-to-phone why can't i set speaker enabled before call is established?

Tags: ios, sinch

i'm using sinch iOS SDK.  i want to set the speaker enabled by default while the call is connecting so the ringing tone will also be heard on speaker but this isn't possible through `sinchClient.audioController().enableSpeaker()` because that can only be called in `callDidEstablish` which happens after the call was answered.
so the ringing always sounds through the device, not on speaker.
i've worked around this by manipulating AVAudioSession on my own.  but i don't understand why does this limitation exist?

Answer (score 0):

it should play on the speaker, are you getting the same error from our sample apps?

```
- (id<SINAudioController>)audioController {
  return [[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] client] audioController];
}

- (void)setCall:(id<SINCall>)call {
  _call = call;
  _call.delegate = self;
}

#pragma mark - UIViewController Cycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  if ([self.call direction] == SINCallDirectionIncoming) {
    [self setCallStatusText:@""];
    [self showButtons:kButtonsAnswerDecline];
    [[self audioController] startPlayingSoundFile:[self pathForSound:@"incoming.wav"] loop:YES];
  } else {
    [self setCallStatusText:@"calling..."];
    [self showButtons:kButtonsHangup];
  }
}
```

Comment: i also got same prob that incoming call ring not play like real incoming ring tone that play on device headphone.